# Geometry type and create trigger for that in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I want to create a trigger (before inserting trigger), to check the geometry type weather is point, polygon, line, or multi-polygon. After that, I want to set the color property. How can I do this?

I am using postgresql 9.4. My OS is Windows 10.

Table Name: Test, column(s): geoData and color.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_color()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
if(st_geometrytype(NEW.geoData) like 'ST_Point') then
       INSERT INTO "Test"("color") VALUES (red);
          NEW.color = 'red';
elseif(st_geometrytype(NEW.geoData) like 'ST_Polygon') then
       -- your logic here, for example: 
          NEW.color = 'green';
elseif(st_geometrytype(NEW.geoData) like 'ST_Linestring') then
       -- your logic here, for example: 
          NEW.color = 'yellow';
elseif(st_geometrytype(NEW.geoData) like 'ST_MultiPolygon') then
    NEW.color = 'blue';
else
    NEW.color = 'black';
end if;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION trigger_color()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

It shows me :

```
ERROR: record "new" has no field "geodata"
SQL state: 42703
Context: SQL statement "SELECT (st_geometrytype(NEW.geoData) like 'ST_Point')"
PL/pgSQL function trigger_color() line 3 at IF
```

How i can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

In your trigger before function (using plpgsql language), you can try something like:

```
if (st_geometrytype(NEW.geom) like 'ST_Point') then
        -- your logic here, for example: 
           NEW.color = 'red';
end if;
```

Comment: please see the edited code in the above question, i have one issue.

Comment: @Gary Check you geometry field name. Probably "geom" or "the_geom". With capital letter, if any, consider the use of double quotes for your field.

Comment: Thank you but as i mentioned in my question, table name is: Test and it has two columns: geoData and color. i used double quotes too. but error occurs when i fired insert query  :: `INSERT INTO "Test"("geoData")
    VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(25.124 44.215)'));
`     Shows the following error :: `ERROR: function st_geometrytype(geography) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Context: PL/pgSQL function trigger_color1() line 3 at IF `

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_color1()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
if(st_geometrytype(NEW."geoData") like 'ST_Point') then
          NEW.color = 'red';
elseif(st_geometrytype(NEW."geoData") like 'ST_Polygon') then
       -- your logic here, for example: 
          NEW.color = 'green';
elseif(st_geometrytype(NEW."geoData") like 'ST_Linestring') then
       -- your logic here, for example: 
          NEW.color = 'yellow';
elseif(st_geometrytype(NEW."geoData") like 'ST_MultiPolygon') then
 NEW.color = 'blue';
else
 NEW.color = 'black';
end if;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'`

Comment: You are using geography type and, as the error says, ST_geometryType does not exist with that datatype. You can probably cast using: "NEW."geoData"::geometry"

Comment: Thank you but what does it mean: **cast using: "NEW."geoData"::geometry"** Sorry i am not getting the exact. please explain a li'll bit more.

Comment: simply you need transform object type because in lat/long st_makepoint return geography type. That depend of spatial reference format. Twice type exists : geographic coordinate system (spherical representation)>>geography type and projected coordinate system (cartesian representation) >> geometry